# Two different form login templates

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

my question is: is it possible to have two different login templates using the same firewall in symfony2? You may ask why do I need this? Well, one of them should be rendered typically after clicking sign in button. In turn the second one would appear when user starts his checkout process clicking on button in his shopping cart. Then ideally he should be able to choose on the same page to login normally or to continue buying as a guest. So this is the difference between these two templates:

1. Pure symfony2 login form
2. Pure symfony2 login form + option to choose buying as a guest

Any idea guys how to distinct them with symfony2 login structure hidden magic? Or maybe it should be solved somehow differently? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

you can have as many login form as you want, only constraints with login form is to post to check_path.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my problem well. I know I can have multpile forms on my website and I do have two of them now. But the third one should have different layout. The problem is when I post invalid login data to login_check action it redirects me behind scenes back to the login path defined in security.yml and displays the default login form template, not the second one with guest option. I just don't know how to determine after redirecting back with errors which layout should I display.